# Do these dents warrant replacing the doors altogether?

Tags: subaru, body-work, dent

Thanks to a deer, a friend got some dents in her driver's side doors and a crack in her bumper just under the headlight. A local mechanic said the doors and bumper will have to be replaced altogether and estimated the cost at $3500, including $650 for each of two replaced doors and something like 20 hours of labor.

This seems extreme to me given the damage, and I thought it might be a cheap fix at a body shop. Am I mistaken? Note that both doors still work perfectly, the damage is aesthetic. But I am not the car's owner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$650 will be the price for a door shell. However, you can't just order a 'blue door' from Subaru - you'll get a basic unpainted door. It then needs to be painted and matched to the existing color of the car, and all the internals need to be transferred over.

On a vehicle that new, you can't easily pick up matching parts in a junk yard (if it was a 2005 or older, I'd get them out of a junker, but this looks like a 2015/2016, which just don't exist in junk yards)

So, the price for replacement sounds pretty accurate. You might suggest that she calls a PDR (Paintless Dent Repair) company to see if they can help for much less - but I've never used them personally (my Subaru wears it's dents like badges of honor...), so I don't know the extent of their abilities.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't look that bad. i would recommend pulling it out instead of changing the whole door. if i were you i would try to pull the door by using the famous heat gun technique; but at the same time it looks it was forced this isn't just a dent, it looks deep. so i would go down with replacing the back door and repair the front door which can save you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The damage seems superficial. I don't see why the doors or bumper or doors would need to be replaced.

The crack in the bumper can be patched from the back with glass fiber and resin.

The door dents can be pulled out using a door puller.

Answer (score -2):

Yes get both door skins and bumper off Amazon may as well replace the electric motors while you have them all apart.  Make sure you torque the bolts down good and gave plenty of body clips before you start.

Also grab a plasti dip kit from dipyourcar.com in whatever color you like.  Costs a couple hundred bucks but looks sweet.  I prefer black or white but you can go nuts if you want with pearls

Gl.

Comment: Replace the window motors and plastidip the car? Why?

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Were you trying to add details to our question or trying to comment on another post?

Comment: It's a 2016 model year car; why on earth would you.... oh, never mind.....